# How can I prepend code to the \tableofcontents command using etoolbox?

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, bookmarks, etoolbox

This started by the need to have a table of contents entry in my PDF bookmarks. After accomplishing that, I decided that I wanted to have it always appear **bold** (supported as of PDF 1.4).

I would like to use `etoolbox` to get this working:

```
\preto<hook>{<code>}
\pretocmd{<command>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
%    \preto\tableofcontents{% Something like this
%      \bookmarksetupnext{bold=true}
%      \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{bkm\contentsname}
%    }
```

This way, everytime `\tableofcontents` is called, a bookmark will be created with bold formatting.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%    \preto\tableofcontents{% Something like this
%      \bookmarksetupnext{bold=true}
%      \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{bkm\contentsname}
%    }


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Ablutophobia}
\section{Ergophobia}
\section{Nomophobia}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: I recommend `xpatch` for this stuff.

Comment: The `interfaces` package also allows you to modify the appearance of the pdf bookmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage is correct. So, fundamentally you can do the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd\tableofcontents{%
  \bookmarksetupnext{bold=true}%
  \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{bkm\contentsname}%
}{}{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Ablutophobia}
\section{Ergophobia}
\section{Nomophobia}

\end{document}
```

You have to be cautious about the location of the mark. In the above example this doesn't seem like a problem, as the hyperlink from the bookmark lands where the **Contents** starts in the PDF. However, it may be that some "administration" is performed before placing **Content**, which could introduce a gap between the jump mark and the text placement.

---

Another approach - somewhat oldschool - would be to use

```
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \bookmarksetupnext{bold=true}%
  \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{bkm\contentsname}%
  \oldtableofcontents
}
```

The above provides a similar `\pretocmd` interface, if you don't want to use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Comment: Great! I was so close. I did not think about "administration" factors. If an example of where that happens should come to mind, please do share.

Comment: @macmadness86: Just add some regular text before `\tableofcontents` to see that the hyperlink jump might not be on point.